# Dict inside the list and TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I noticed it's a popular TypeError but I cannot find solution. Look at my code and say what's wrong, please:

```
import random
players_list = []

def add_player():
    possible_flags = {'is_computer', 'is_human'}
    decision = -1
    while decision != '0':
        player_name = input('Give a name: ')

        while player_flag not in possible_flags
            player_flag = input("Type 'is_computer' or 'is_human': ") #is_computer or is_human

        players_list.append({'player_name': player_name, 'player_flag': player_flag, 'player_decision': None})

        decision = input('Do you want add a new player [1]? To leave type [1] ')


def play():
    options = {1: 'rock', 2: 'paper', 3: 'scissors', 4: 'lizard', 5: 'Spock'}
    for i in players_list:
        if('is_computer' in players_list[i]):
            player_decision = random.choice(options)
        elif('is_player' in players_list[i]):
            player_decision = input()

        player_list[i]['player_decision'] = options[player_decision]


add_player()
play()
```

The problem is there:

```
if('is_computer' in players_list[i]):
```

I tried also:

```
if('is_computer' in players_list[i]['player_flag']):
```

But that also does not work. 
I just don't understand it. Did I make a mistake by placing dict inside the list? I would be grateful for any links to articles about it.

Many thanks

Comment: `for i in players_list:\n...players_list[i]`: Python isn't javascript.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in players_list
```

`i` is not an index, but the element itself. You may want to rewrite the snippet as:

```
for player in player_list:
    if player['player_flag'] == 'is_computer':
        ...
```